# CakePHP Saving Model in another controller

Tags: cakephp

So I've just started a small project in CakePHP and I'm unsure how best to cope with the following.
Say I have Users, Posts and PostsUser. PostsUser. Users have a hasMany through relationship with Posts.
PostsUser represents a user having read a post (it has userId, postId and a created date).

Now in my list of posts I'd like to be able to click a link to mark a post as read which to a "markRead" method in PostsController.

Now finally the question, how do I save a new PostsUser in PostController, I've read about adding $uses and adding PostsUser to this but this doesn't seem to work.

Secondly is this even the correct way to do things? Having a posts/markRead/14 url seems nice but I'd be willing to change this around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Controller::uses for that is considered as bad practice. Associated models should be accessed through the associations.

Inside your PostsController::markAsRead() method you can use ClassRegistry::init('PostsUser') to get an instance of the model and call a method from that object.

Or use [Controller::loadModel()](http://api20.cakephp.org/class/controller#method-ControllerloadModel).

If it is just about the naming of the link you can also have PostsUsersController::markAsRead() and [use the router](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html) to route /posts/markAsRead/:id to the PostsUsersController.